# Does Tor entry point store my ISP information?

Tags: ip-address, guard-node

Does Tor entry point stores my ISP addresses after I disconnect from the Tor system?

Answer (score 1):

The entry point into the Tor network (so called guard node) sees your real IP address. Depending on the policy of the relay operator it could save every connecting IP address. This can be done with or without Tor. In general it is considered good practise to *not save* any data.

Comment: IMHO storing *any* logs in Tor node breaks the entire concept of anonymity online.

Comment: No. Tor works also with malicious relay operators. It has privac by design. So as long as there is one good acting operator or operators with conflicting goals the privacy can't get degraded.

Comment: sadly - yju are right here. That's why I'm in my project incorporating other darknets and tools like Perspectives project. I even was offered by russian FSB to help them to set up a network of malicious relays...